# What is the meaning of "Lifetime_Remaining%" in smartctl?

Tags: linux, disk, smartctl

Recently I had an `fsck error on boot`, where I had to run fsck manually. So, I did it and the problem disappeared. After that i run `smartctl -a /dev/sda` and i saw the following attribute

```
    ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
    201 Lifetime_Remaining%     0x0023   100   100   005    Pre-fail  Always       -       6
```

What is the meaning? Is it something I should worry about?
I searched in other similar questions but I didn't find an answer. My operating system is Ubuntu 20.04

Here is the smartctl output

```
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.4.0-58-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Marvell based SanDisk SSDs
Device Model:     SanDisk SD8SN8U-512G-1006
Serial Number:    174668800539
LU WWN Device Id: 5 001b44 8b6963006
Firmware Version: X4120006
User Capacity:    512.110.190.592 bytes [512 GB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Form Factor:      < 1.8 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2 T13/2015-D revision 3
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.2, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sat Jan  2 19:29:46 2021 EET
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                    was completed without error.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (  120) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x53) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (  43) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 32
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       19828
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   005    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       6477
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       2401
171 Program_Fail_Count      0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
172 Erase_Fail_Count        0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
173 Avg_Write/Erase_Count   0x0032   100   100   005    Old_age   Always       -       6
174 Unexpect_Power_Loss_Ct  0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       145
176 Erase_Fail_Count_Chip   0x0022   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       4352
181 Program_Fail_Cnt_Total  0x0022   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
184 End-to-End_Error        0x003b   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   032   061   ---    Old_age   Always       -       32 (Min/Max 17/61)
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   100   ---    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 SATA_CRC_Error          0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
201 Lifetime_Remaining%     0x0023   100   100   005    Pre-fail  Always       -       6
230 Perc_Write/Erase_Count  0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       578 578 85
241 Total_Writes_GiB        0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       430151
242 Total_Reads_GiB         0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       344983
243 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       743567
244 Thermal_Throttle        0x0032   000   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
249 TLC_NAND_GB_Writes      0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       3155

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that says that your drive not worn out at all and has 100% of its life ahead of it.

when it gets down to 5% then  it's time to panic.

> 194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   032   061

32 looks OK but 61 is a bit high, make sure your case has sufficient ventilation.

Comment: Thanks man, I saw the RAW_VALUE which is 6, and i thought that is critical.